# how do i Get the first character of each item in a list scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want it to extract all the first words in the list.
Example:

(first 'hello world asd fdas qwerty )

return:

h w a f q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (first-char lst)
  (map (lambda (w)
         (string->symbol
          (string
           (string-ref
            (symbol->string w) 0))))
       lst))
```

For example:

```
(first-char '(hello world asd fdas qwerty))
=> '(h w a f q)
```